# Problem with checkboxes (all checked) when listing items from an API in Angular v12

Tags: angular

I have a list of items from a query from an API (php file listall.php), from that list I need to select through checkbox the ones that are needed for the next process. The bad thing is that when I show the list of items, they all appear with the checkboxes checked.

My code in HTML component:

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let art of articles">
           <th scope="row"> 
           <input name="{{art.url}}" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange()" [(ngModel)]="art.isselected"></th>
           <td><font style="color: rgb(0, 97, 177)">{{art.url}}</font></td></tr>
```

Manage URL TS Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticlesService } from '../../articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-url',
  templateUrl: './manage-url.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-url.component.scss']
})

export class ManageUrlComponent implements OnInit {
    
  articles: any = null;
  art: any = {
    num: null,
    url: null,
    isselected: false,
  };
  
  clearfield() {
    this.art.url = "";
  }
  constructor(private articlesService: ArticlesService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.listAll();
    this.art.url = "";
  }
  onChange(){
    console.log(this.articles);
  }
  listAll() {
    this.articlesService.listAll().subscribe(result => this.articles = result);
  }
  insert() {
    this.articlesService.insert(this.art).subscribe(datos => {
      if (data['result']=='OK') {
        alert(data['message']);
        this.listAll();
      }
    });
  }
  select(num: number) {
    this.articlesService.select(num).subscribe(result => this.art = result[0]);
     this.listAll();
  }
  Thereisarticles() {
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: To help you, it would be interesting to know the value of 'result' in here: this.articlesService.listAll().subscribe(result => this.articles = result);

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a single variable for all the list of checkboxes so that's why you have all of them pointed to a single one and all get on and off together.

If this is your problem then seperately declare the checkbox variable of add the checkbox on and off on basis of the results list and add a isSelected object to the all the item which sets the particular check box on and off of it.

Comment: Ok. But if I manually declare this array:                                                               
       this._urllist = [
       {num: 1, url: "https://feeds.elpais.com/mrss-s/pages/ep/site/elpais.com/section/america/portada/", isselected: false},
       {num: 2, url: "https://www.critica.com.pa/rss/recent/index.xml", isselected: false},
       {num: 3, url: "https://www.elmetrodepanama.com/feed/", isselected: false}... etc etc...
    ]
And I show the same list with the same checkboxes does not give the error of checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

A checkBox only has two values: true or false. If you need store this "true/false" in a series of checkBox you need use an array

```
selected:boolean[]=[] //in your .ts declare an empty array

<tr *ngFor="let art of articles;let i=index">
    <th scope="row"> 
         <input name="{{art.url}}" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selected[i]"></th>
    <td><font style="color: rgb(0, 97, 177)">{{art.url}}</font></td>
</tr>
```

When you want to know what articles are selected

```
this.articlesSelected=this.articles
              .filter((_,index)=>this.selected[index])
```

Yes, in filter, map, forEach you can use a second argument that is the "index"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now with your code all the (checkboxes-1) are checked, the only checkbox unchecked is the last. one

Answer (score 0):

Try like that

```
 <tr *ngFor="let art of articles">
           <th scope="row"> 
           <input name="{{art.url}}" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(art.url)" [value]="selectedUrls.includes(art.url)"></th>
           <td><font style="color: rgb(0, 97, 177)">{{art.url}}</font></td></tr>
```

and ts component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticlesService } from '../../articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-url',
  templateUrl: './manage-url.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-url.component.scss']
})

export class ManageUrlComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedUrls:string[] = [];
  articles: any = null;
  art: any = {
    num: null,
    url: null,
    isselected: false,
  };
  
  clearfield() {
    this.art.url = "";
  }
  constructor(private articlesService: ArticlesService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.listAll();
    this.art.url = "";
  }

  onChange(url: string){
     const index = selectedUrls.indexOf(url);
      if (index > -1) {
       // remove item from array
        selectedUrls.splice(index, 1);
      } 
      else {
         // add item to array
         selectedUrls.push(url);
     }
  }

  listAll() {
    this.articlesService.listAll().subscribe(result => this.articles = result);
  }
  insert() {
    this.articlesService.insert(this.art).subscribe(datos => {
      if (data['result']=='OK') {
        alert(data['message']);
        this.listAll();
      }
    });
  }
  select(num: number) {
    this.articlesService.select(num).subscribe(result => this.art = result[0]);
     this.listAll();
  }
  Thereisarticles() {
    return true;
  } 
}
```